# How to identify programmatically generate TextViews in swift?

Tags: swift

I need a way to identify programmatically generated text views. The problem is that I am creating a list of textviews, and I want to control them with code. How can I set and ID or something to know which one is which?

Comment: Set the `.tag` property to some integer

Comment: Instead of using the `tag` property you should keep an array with your text views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tag`

```
let textview = UITextView()
textview.tag = your value in int
```